# Using angular js form validations in <form:input> tag

Tags: angularjs, jsp-tags, spring-form

I have created a jsp page having a spring form. I want to validate the form using angular js. When I try to add **required** and **ng-model** attributes inside `<form:input>` tag, I'm getting exception Jasper exception `equal symbol expected` and `Attribute ng-model invalid for tag input according to TLD` in the line where i added these attributes.

What is the procedure to make my logic work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 things you can try:

First one: Probably the neatest, and I think this should work:

```
<form:input path="usrname" maxlength="12" required="required"/>
```

So required='required' instead of just required

Second one: Forget about Angular Validation, and use Spring Validation methods. Maybe this isn't the thing you're searching for.

Third one: Isn't it possible for you to forget about `<form:input>` tags, and use `<input>` tags instead? Maybe not.

Fourth one: You can try to give your form:input tag an id, and at the bottom of your page, run a simple jQuery script. I know, this isn't the neatest thing to do, but maybe it works.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form:input path="someinput" id="someinput"/>
    </body>
<script>
        $("#someinput").attr('required', ''); 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kornelito. Your answer solved my required attribute problem. Even my `ng-model` is getting jasper exception. Can you please help me out in that?

Comment: Yes offcourse. Could you please post your code where you use ng-model.

Comment: `<html>  
    <body ng-app="myApp">  
        <form:input path="Name" ng-model="uName"/>  
    </body>    
  
</html>`  

This is how my sample code looks like

Comment: try to use data-ng-model instead of ng-model. Let me know if this works

Comment: Do you use the spring form explicitly?

Comment: data-ng-model is not working. And yes. I've included `<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>` at the beginning of page.

Comment: are you using Spring V3?

Comment: I'm using Spring V2.5.4

Comment: Use minimum Spring V3, and it should work. 'Custom' attributes in form:input are supported in version 3. Lower versions of spring doesn't support them