# Unable to use Angular JS Form Validation with Spring form tags

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, forms, validation

I have created a JSP page using Spring Form tags and I'm trying to validate my form using AngularJS Form Validations. But form validations are not working.

Here's the snippet of the form:

```html
<html ng-app>
    <body>
        <form:form name="signupForm" class="form-horizontal" action="/admin"
            method="POST" modelAttribute="userVO"  novalidate = "novalidate">

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : signupForm.username.$error.required && signupForm.username.$dirty}">
                    <label for="userName" class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="text-align:center;">Username<span class="rqrd">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <form:input path="userName" placeholder="UserName" class="form-control" ng-model="signupForm.username" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <span ng-show="signupForm.username.$error.required && !signupForm.username.$pristine" class="help-block">
                    Username is required
                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : signupForm.password.$error.required && signupForm.password.$dirty}">
                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="text-align:center;">Password<span class="rqrd">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <form:password path="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="signupForm.password" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <span ng-show="signupForm.password.$error.required && !signupForm.password.$pristine" class="help-block">
                    Password is required
                    </span>
            </div>
</body>
</form:form>
</html>
```

I've included the Spring form tag library as :
`<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`
 and 
angular.min.js and bootstrap using cdn's:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

According to this, when the username is **not pristine (or it's dirty)** and it's **empty** then, it should show the line mentioned within span tag. But it's not showing it and in addition to this if this is the case, it should add **'has-error'** class to the div and that's also not happening when checked on developer tools in chrome and firefox.

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717836/using-angular-js-form-validations-in-forminput-tag) and used **data-ng-** instead of **ng-** but issue wasn't resolved.

I'm not sure what's the exact issue so I'm unable to fix it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the action and use the ng-submit

```
<html ng-app>
    <body>
        <form:form name="signupForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submitForm" novalidate>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : signupForm.username.$error.required && signupForm.username.$dirty}">
                    <label for="userName" class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="text-align:center;">Username<span class="rqrd">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <form:input path="userName" placeholder="UserName" class="form-control" ng-model="signupForm.username" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <span ng-show="signupForm.username.$error.required && !signupForm.username.$pristine" class="help-block">
                    Username is required
                    </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : signupForm.password.$error.required && signupForm.password.$dirty}">
                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="text-align:center;">Password<span class="rqrd">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <form:password path="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="signupForm.password" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <span ng-show="signupForm.password.$error.required && !signupForm.password.$pristine" class="help-block">
                    Password is required
                    </span>
            </div>
</body>
</form:form>
</html>
```

Check out this fiddle
https://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/xFcdI